# Adding a generic of variable datatype to a set Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, insertion

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
Class Example {
    private Set<A> setA = new HashSet<A>();
    private Set<B> setB = new HashSet<B>();


    //setters/getters

    . . .


    // this method is where I don't know what to put
    public boolean addToList(Set<?> set, <?> generic){
          set.add(generic)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Example ex = new Example();
         ex.addToList(ex.getSetA(), new A());
         ex.addToList(ex.getSetB() new B());
    }
}
```

I want to write a method to execute over sets of different datatypes. I find that this will be a little more practical than writing add/get/remove methods for each of a dozen sets.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: `public <T> boolean addToList(Set<T> set, T generic){` should work, but maybe you could use a map (class as key and your Set as value, ie. A.class => setA, B.class => setB) and addToList becomes `map.get(generic.class).add(generic)`

Comment: Why do you need anything more than `ex.getSetA().add(new A())`?

Comment: @Andy Turner I could also be adding new B depending on the user's query. This is only a simplified example. I'm dealing with many sets and just wanted something cleaner than writing the same methods over again to handle each datatype

Comment: You need to show a more illustrative example, because for what you've got here, you don't need to write the same methods over again.

Comment: I disagree. Examples are supposed to be trivial but inductive. Anything I can do with 2 sample sets I can do with 100, but it's much simpler to look at the smaller sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need parameterized method

```
public <T> boolean addToList(Set<T> set, T generic){
      set.add(generic)
}
```

Comment: Could I ask for more clarification on this method declaration? Particularly the <T> part in "public <T> boolean"

Comment: @user3466773 it's a type variable. It's just saying that generic has to be the same as (or a subtype of) the type of the elements in the set.

Comment: As Andy Turner says. The compiler will just make sure that when you call this method if you pass a Set<T> you will pass an instance of T as well, T being any type possible

Answer (score 1):

(Unless you want to make something if the `add` method succeeds / fails, you should use `void` instead of your generic type.)

Here is an example that should work:

```
public void addToAList(Set<A> set, A generic){
      set.add(generic);
}
```

However, if you want to make a generic `addToList` function, you need to push it way further, as you'll need to compare classes between the Set and the Object you are inputting in your method. Considering that you cannot call `getClass()` or `.class` on an Object, I think your easiest (**but not the best at all**) way to do here is to cut it down into two methods.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd have to do something more for checking the values themselves, but I really just needed to know how to construct the method I wanted to handle sets of varying datatypes